# How to gather DNS A record requests?

Tags: tcpdump

I need to record all outgoing `A` records on a RedHat PC. I tried using `tcpdump`:

```
tcpdumpdns=OUTPUT-FILENAME-HERE
nohup tcpdump -K dst port 53 -w $tcpdumpdns > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

It makes an output file like:

```
19:26:12.185392 IP 172.16.0.6.57977 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 51198+ A? yahoo.com. (27)
```

So I need to process that to get the `yahoo.com`:

```
echo $tcpdumpdns | awk '/ A\? / {u = NF - 1; print $u}' | sed 's/^www.//g; s/.$//g' | sort -u
```

Is there any better solution to gather all the outgoing `A` record requests?

p.s.: collecting DNS A records is only needed to have an up-to-date list of websites that are reachable via HTTPS. So I can generate xml files for HTTPSEverywhere Firefox Add-on. So this is just a part of a script.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you provided?

Comment: do you have a GUI env, if so using wireshark-gtk is an easier solution, since you can filter there much easily.

Comment: @Hanan N.: GUI is not an option. this is needed to be automatic.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: I hope nothing. But I asked because I'm open for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use Wireshark:

```
tshark -f "udp port 53" -Y "dns.qry.type == A and dns.flags.response == 0"
```

Comment: I get `tshark: "A" cannot be found among the possible values for dns.qry.type.`

Comment: To address @JackO'Connor issue, the decimal value for a type A DNS record is 1. Therefore, this should work: `tshark -f "udp port 53" -Y "dns.qry.type == 1 and dns.flags.response == 0"`

Answer (score 17):

If you don't have wireshark installed then

```
tcpdumpdns=/tmp/tcpdumps
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" | tee $tcpdumpdns
```

should work for you. As you wanted to limit the output to the second to last value then I would parse your log file with:

```
grep -E 'A\?' $tcpdumpdns |sed -e 's/^.*A? //' -e 's/ .*//'|sort -u
```

If you want it live then:

```
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

should do it, (here sed and awk are interchangeable; and I would pick awk.)

Comment: `grep -E 'A\?' $tcpdumpdns |sed 's/^.*A? //;s/ .*//'|sort -u` is less to type